# How to submit yii 2 form onload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, yii

```
Pjax::begin();
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
echo $form->field($model, 'testdata', [
                  'inputOptions' => [
                  'class' => 'form-control input-xsmall input-inline' ],
                  ])->label(Yii::t('app', 'Records : '))
                  ->dropDownList(['10'=> 10, '15' => 15, '20' => 20, '50' => 50], ['onchange'=>"this.form.submit();"]);

ActiveForm::end();
Pjax::end();
```

The form above allows me to submit form on change event.
How can I make the form submit onload?

Comment: why do you need a form if you are doing submit on page load?

Comment: for the first time i get the value chosen in drop down and store it in a session. and then i move to another page and go backend the same page, the drop down list will show my selection but it is not submitting it. so what i show and what i submit will not be tally

Answer (score -1):

You can use `onloadFunctions` as shown below. You need to define the property inside your controller. [Source](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/8045-solved-how-to-run-a-javascript-function-on-body-load/)

```
<body onload="<?php echo Yii::app()->controller->onloadFunction; ?">
```

Controller :

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
     public $onloadFunction='AJavascriptFunction();';
}
```